# Binary body in postman

Tags: binary, postman

I'm trying to send a request in binary format in postman, but it is necessary in the body no with a file.

Is there a way for do this?

Thank you all!!

Comment: This question seems to be about Postman usage with no relationship to MuleSoft.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am using a mulesoft flow. Postman is the tool im using for do the request

Answer (score 0):

Postman allows to set the body in a text based format (plain text, JSON, XML, etc) or as a binary file. If you try to copy binary data into the text box it will probably be corrupted. It is best to have the binary data in a file and attach the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send the binary as plain text it would be risky, I would suggest you to send it as a multipart format. In postman, in body you can select 'form-data' and give any key and in the 'key' field click on the drop down and select 'File' and then select the .txt file containing your binary from your local. In the mule flow give a 'set-payload' connector and in the MIME Type select 'application/octet-stream' for binary.

Comment: the problem is that I can't dispose of a file, it has to be as a payload during the whole flow the mule system-process-system. The request is used by each api, and this binary data has to travel through this apis, system -> process -> system

Comment: If you send it as a multipart/formdata it will be as a payload only. Wherever you want to access the file just access payload.parts..content and you will be able to access the file content